# Flutter) How to draw a diagonal line from the canvas with a dashed line?

Tags: flutter, canvas

I'm going to draw lines using canvas.
I want to draw a dashed line like the image below.

I succeeded in drawing a dashed line with two points with the same Y-axis with the following code.

```
  void _drawDashedLine(
    Canvas canvas,
    Paint paint,
    Size size,
    Offset p1,
    Offset p2,
  ) {
    // dashed width and distance
    const int dashWidth = 5;
    const int dashSpace = 5;

    double startX = p1.dx;
    double startY = p1.dy;

    while (startX < p2.dx) {
      canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(startX, startY), Offset(startX + dashWidth, startY), paint);
      startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }
```

However, I'm failed to draw a diagonal line like the image below (the blue dot in the image is p1, p2).

This is the code I tried.

```
  void _drawDashedLine(
    Canvas canvas,
    Paint paint,
    Size size,
    Offset p1,
    Offset p2,
  ) {
    const int dashWidth = 5;
    const int dashSpace = 5;

    double startX = p1.dx;
    double startY = p1.dy;

    while (startX < p2.dx) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, startY),
          Offset(startX + dashWidth, startY + dashWidth), paint);
      startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
      startY += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }
```

This always changes the value of the Y-axis to be constant, so that it is drawn at a completely different angle.

I think I should calculate the Y-axis by the angle of the two points p1, p2, so can I know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already guessed, we need to determine the angle formed by the two points `p1` and `p2` first. The dart's math library is our little helper here. Let's say we have the points

```
final p1 = Offset(50, 50);
final p2 = Offset(250, 150);
```

[image]

and feed the difference between the two points horizontal and vertical position to the `math.atan2()` method, we get the angle in radians

```
final dX = p2.dx - p1.dx;
final dY = p2.dy - p1.dy;
final angle = math.atan2(dY, dX);
```

The second step is calculating the actual width of the line. If it's a simple horizontal or vertical line things are quite simple, if it's at an angle which is not a multiple of 90° things are - a bit - more complicated. If we add two 'virtual' lines to our line to form a right-triangle, we can use the Pythagorean theorem [image: (a^2+b^2=c^2)] to calculate the length of the line [image].

```
final totalLength = math.sqrt(math.pow(dX, 2) + math.pow(dY, 2));
```

[image]

With this two steps we're ready to go. Starting from `p1` we move into the direction of `p2`, sum up the segments we already draw and if it exceeds `totalLength` our line is complete.

```
  void _drawDashedLine(
    Canvas canvas,
    Paint paint,
    Offset p1,
    Offset p2,
  ) {
    const int dashWidth = 5;
    const int dashSpace = 5;

    final dX = p2.dx - p1.dx;
    final dY = p2.dy - p1.dy;
    final angle = math.atan2(dY, dX);
    final totalLength = math.sqrt(math.pow(dX, 2) + math.pow(dY, 2));

    double drawnLength = 0.0;
    final cos = math.cos(angle);
    final sin = math.sin(angle);

    while (drawnLength < totalLength) {
      canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(p1.dx + cos * drawnLength, p1.dy + sin * drawnLength),
          Offset(p1.dx + cos * (drawnLength + dashWidth),
              p1.dy + sin * (drawnLength + dashWidth)),
          paint);

      drawnLength += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }
```